# Spacewalk From Earth To Luna

Tags: gravity, design-alternative, eva

A question that I have not seen but have been curious about…… I have a little bit above average (I think) of how gravity works or what gravity is but can’t figure this out; Let’s pretend that we make some footwear that would let us walk on empty air that doesn’t use quarks, atoms or molecules. Walking on nothing, so to speak. Would someone be able to walk from Earth all the way to Luna (taking time, distance, etc… out of the equation) unimpeded or would the gravity exerted by Earth keep them from doing so, almost like they had a rope tied around their waste? Obviously said person wouldn’t reach speeds needed to break free from Earth’s gravity but would their constant forward motion give them the energy to push thru Earth’s grip or would gravity allow them to keep moving but only permitting the following the contour or gravity field of Earth? Sorry if my question is hard to understand but I can think of no other way to ask it right now……

Comment: It would be like climbing a stair, a very, very tall stair, until you reach the point where the gravity from earth and luna are equal. Then you would going down a (relatively) shorter stair.

Comment: Obligatory XKCDs [stairs](https://what-if.xkcd.com/126/) and [Earth-Moon Fire Pole](https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/)

Comment: From reading both links (thank you, btw) I gather it would be possible to walk from earth to the moon, in that scenario anyway?

Comment: Don't forget your speed around the Earth, and the fact that the Moon is moving in its orbit, you'd have to set out walking toward where the Moon is going to be, not where it is now.  I believe this would be the first instance of a Hohmann transfer stroll.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you don't exactly understand how either gravity or escape velocity works.

To give a simplistic understanding, gravity is a force that pulls you (and everything else) towards the center of the object. Earth's gravity pulls you toward it, but you can overcome that gravity by exerting a greater force in the opposite direction, and then you will move upward. For example, if you jump or climb stairs or use an elevator (so that the machine exerts the force on you), then since the "upward" force on you is greater than the "downward" force of gravity, you will go up. However, with no other forces than gravity acting on you, you will accelerate *downwards* at a rate of 1G (9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>).

*Any* sustained force greater than the force of gravity will eventually let you get arbitrarily far from Earth. Obviously jumping only works while your feet are touching the ground, but other methods, such as continually burning rocket engines, will be able to get you outside of Earth's gravity, regardless of your speed. If you keep going upwards (climbing up stairs, for example) at a rate of 1 m/s, you eventually will get arbitrarily far, although you will have to be exerting effort the entire time. As soon as you stop exerting effort, you will accelerate downwards again, as Earth's gravity is the only force acting on you.

Escape velocity is simply the minimum velocity that allows you to *stop working altogether* and still get out. The idea is that if you're going fast enough and then you stop pushing forward, you will indeed get slowed down by Earth's gravity (downward acceleration can make you go down faster or it can make your upward speed slow down), but the farther you are from Earth, the less its gravity affects you, and the less you slow down. Eventually, you are far enough that Earth's gravity is insignificant in terms of slowing you down, and you have "escaped" Earth's gravity. Note that if you don't need to "stop working" (by shutting down rocket engines, for example), then you don't ever need to reach escape velocity to get to the same point where Earth's gravity is insignificant: just keep the rocket engines roaring.

In general, there is nothing "magical" about gravity that keeps you close unless you reach escape velocity. You can constantly exert *just enough* force to move upwards, or you can accelerate quickly and then stop, or somewhere in between. There is no "rope" making sure you can't leave, just a downward force that can be counteracted with *more* upward force.

Comment: I have a general awareness  of how escape velocity works and also gravity but certainly not at the levels that a physicist does. It may be that I did a poor job of framing  my question? That said, you were able to make enough sense of it to give me an answer so maybe not? Regardless, thank you for answering, I can now put that question to bed…